# Shuffle a square numpy array, but retain correspondence between row and column indices

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, shuffle

If I have a square *and symmetric* matrix, for example,

```
[[0 3 2]
 [3 8 4]
 [2 4 5]]
```

I do not want to shuffle rows only or columns only. instead,

how can I, *for example* (not the following in the strict order as written, but instead at random):

- shuffle the matrix in numpy so that row *and* column 1 are moved together to row and column 3,
- while row *and* column 3 are moved to row and column 2
- and row *and* column 2 are moved to row and column 1

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for can be done with so-called matrix conjugation:

```
perm_mat = np.random.permutation(np.eye(len(a),dtype=np.int))

out = (perm_mat @ a) @ (np.linalg.inv(perm_mat))
```

Output (random of course):

```
array([[8., 4., 3.],
       [4., 5., 2.],
       [3., 2., 0.]])
```

Or can be done with slicing:

```
np.random.seed(1)
orders = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(a)))
a[orders][:,orders]
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [2, 5, 4],
       [3, 4, 8]])
```